# What is the best way to make the divider between the LinearLayout in android?

Tags: android

[image]

I am going to make the divider now.
But i don't know what is the simple and best way to make divider in android.
If anyone knows about this, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well it's opinion based if you ask me I would say a View with 1dp height with background color set to some light color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method:

Under `res/values/styles.xml`, add a block of code like this:

```
<style name="DividerGray">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0.2dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/divider_gray</item>
</style>
```

Then just use this style in your layout like this:

```
<View style="@style/DividerGray"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout has this feature built in - please check `android:showDividers`, `android:divider` and `android:dividerPadding` attributes of LinearLayout.